# Unknown column keeps on appearing

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have already read the docs of CI however I am still encountering error with regards to my query. I posted my answer hoping you could help me with this.

```
    $code = $_SESSION['affiliate_code'];
    $email  = $this->db->query('select email from affiliates where referral_code = '.$code);
```

What happening is that the query being created looks like this

```
    select email from affiliates where referral_code = dTE7TkDcOa86;
```

but in order to work it should be like

```
    select email from affiliates where referral_code = 'dTE7TkDcOa86';
```

How can I make my code work correctly?
I appreciate your help with this. Thank you.

Comment: Just add quotes, that way it will take that as a string.
$email  = $this->db->query('select email from affiliates where referral_code =" '.$code.'"');

Comment: I did that and same error encountered see other answers below @blacmoon

Comment: $email  = $this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code = '".trim($code)."'");
then change the quotes. If your $code contains $

Comment: echo the $code and check it echoes the correct value

Comment: $code echoes the correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$email = $this->db->query("SELECT email FROM affiliates WHERE referral_code = '$code'");
    $email2 = $email->result_array();
    foreach($email2 as $key) {
        echo $key['email'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$email  = $this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code ='{$code}'");
```

But better would be prepared Statements:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code = ?"); 
$email = $this->db->execute($sql, array($code)); // Or something like this
```

Comment: I tried you solution and I got an error saying 'Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string'

Comment: sorry I am new into this. what do you mean by prepared Statements ?

Comment: $sql  = $this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code = ?");
$email  = $this->db->execute($sql, array($code)); // Or something like this

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
$email  = $this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code = '$code'");
```

Comment: this makes $code a string value and not a variable anymore

Comment: no it will print the value because the outer quotes is double not sigle quotes.

Comment: same with the other answers. I encountered error saying Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string, can you help me with this?

Comment: try this:
 `$this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code = '$code'"); $email=$this->db->get()->row()->email;`

Answer (score 0):

Please try This

```
$email  = $this->db->query("select email from affiliates where referral_code = '".$code."' ");
```

Use Fallowing :-

```
$this->db->select('email')->from('affiliates')->where('referral_code',$code);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using your solution but I got an error stating Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: I used your second solution but still same error encountered

Comment: How you are printing your result.

Comment: I use echo to print

Comment: Please Use print_r($query->results());